# ArrayMap put method pushes elements in strange order

Tags: java, android

I am using ArrayMap for first time in my project and I thought it works just like an array. I expected when I use .put method it inserts it at next index.
But in my case this is not true - after I added all elements one by one the first element I added ended up at index 4 which is kind of strange.

Here are the first three steps which I add elements:

1 - Salads:

[image]

2 - Soups:

[image]

3 - Appetizers:

[image]

So somehow on second step "Soup" element was inserted in index 0 instead of 1 as I was expecting, but strangely on third step "Appetizers" was inserted as expected after "Soup".

This is the code I am using to push key and value pair:

```
function ArrayMap<String, DMType> addElement(String typeKey, DMType type) {
    ArrayMap<String, DMType> types = new ArrayMap<>();
    types.put(typeKey, type);

    return types;
}
```

Am I missing something about the behavior of ArrayMap?

Comment: Try to use LinkedHashMap instead of ArrayMap.

Comment: If you want the Map functionality with order guranteed use LinkedHashMap instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it is misleading because of the name but ArrayMap does no gurantee order unlike arrays.

> ArrayMap is a generic key->value mapping data structure that is
>   designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap.

ArrayMap is actually a Map:

> public class ArrayMap extends SimpleArrayMap implements Map

***If you want the Map functionality with order guranteed use LinkedHashMap instead.***

> LinkedHashMap defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the
>   order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html)

Comment: Will I be able to get element by index if I am using LinkedHashMap?

Comment: No, but if you have the index definetly you have the key so use the key to get the element. But if you use a simple for each loop you will able to iterate over the lements as they are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work as an array, I don't see `Array` in the name but `Map` and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) clearly states that behaves as a generic key->value mapping, more efficient (memory wise) than traditional `HashMap` implementation.

Actually I don't see why you care about the order compared to the insertion one. Data is private inside the class and you have no way to obtain the element by the index, so you are basically wondering about a private implementation which is irrelevant for its usage.

If you really want to understand how it stores its data you should take a look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/ArrayMap.java).

Comment: more efficient than traditional HashMap, memory wise. not speed wise. just to clarify for readers

Comment: Well the code I provided is just a simple part of what I want to achieve!
I need to have List<String, DMType> which I can get the element by the index and the String value. For example I need to know what element was pushed second

Answer (score 1):

ArrayMap does NOT work like an Array, instead, it works like a HashMap with performance optimizations.

The internal sequence of the key-value pair is not guaranteed as it is NOT part of the contract.

In your case, what you really want to use is probably an `ArrayList<Element>`, where the Element class is defined like this:

```
public class Element{
    private final String typeKey;
    private final DMType type;
    public Element(String typeKey, DMType type){
           this.typeKey = typeKey;
           this.type = type;
    }
}
```

If you don't want a new Class just to store the result, and you want to keep the sequence, you can use a `LinkedHashMap<String, DMType>`. As the document specifies:

> Class LinkedHashMap
>
> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Comment: The problem is I don't want to have a new class for that and also I want to be able to easily get element by key.

I am wondering about using ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, DMType>>

Comment: Try LinkedHashMap, as I just modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it works just like an array

No, it works like a map, because it is a map. It is similar to a HashMap, but more memory efficient for smaller data sets.

It's order shouldn't and doesn't matter. Under the hood, it is implemented using 
an array which has an order since arrays do. This inherently gives the ArrayMap an order, but that is not part of it's API anyway. Just like which memory slot your Java objects are in, you shouldn't care about the order here either.

Comment: So I chose wrong type then. 
I actually wanted to use Array functionality with key-value pair like this:
ArrayList<String, DMType>
Is LinkedHashMap the best option here?

PS I know I can use the option ArrayList<NewCombinedClass> but  I don't want to have a new class like this intentionally and also I want to have to possibility to get the element by key as well